# (Python-)Polars Statistics with List Fields

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to play around a bit with polars trying to figure out which way to mold my data into a polars DataFrame. My data consists of lists (or rather fixed-size arrays, but the `pl.Array` support is really lacking) and some extra information. For example:

```py
test = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
data = {
    "list": [test, test + 1],
    "label": ["test", "test2"],
    "some number": [1, 2],
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
```

which produces:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ list            ┆ label ┆ some number │
│ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ list[f64]       ┆ str   ┆ i64         │
╞═════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] ┆ test  ┆ 1           │
│ [2.0, 3.0, 4.0] ┆ test2 ┆ 2           │
└─────────────────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

While this organically aligns with my data, it seems that no list arithmetic is inherently supported, for example to figure out mean and variances of the list elements (i.e. `[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]`. Instead, `df.describe()` produces only `null`:

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬───────┬─────────────┐
│ describe   ┆ list ┆ label ┆ some number │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---         │
│ str        ┆ str  ┆ str   ┆ f64         │
╞════════════╪══════╪═══════╪═════════════╡
│ count      ┆ 2    ┆ 2     ┆ 2.0         │
│ null_count ┆ 0    ┆ 0     ┆ 0.0         │
│ mean       ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ 1.5         │
│ std        ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ 0.707107    │
│ min        ┆ null ┆ test  ┆ 1.0         │
│ max        ┆ null ┆ test2 ┆ 2.0         │
│ median     ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ 1.5         │
│ 25%        ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ 1.0         │
│ 75%        ┆ null ┆ null  ┆ 2.0         │
└────────────┴──────┴───────┴─────────────┘
```

Similarly if I want to compute say covariance matrices, `df.corr()` crashes.

My current approach to this is to unnest the list fields and then get statistics from there:

```py
unnested_df = df.select(pl.col("list").list.to_struct()).unnest("list")
# now .describe() works
```

Is this the way to go? Is there some better way to handle this, with the ultimate goal of visualizing that data?

Comment: I think for now your current approach is the way to go, the List API is still evolving and the Array API has just started.